# Converting Linear to Grid Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

The given code creates a layout with a Linear Layout showing all the folders. It shows all the folders in the horizontal view. I want to convert it into Grid Layout, so that I can accommodate many folders in one screen.

```
val root = LinearLayout(this)
    val file = File("/sdcard/MedProRecordings/").absoluteFile
    if (file.isDirectory == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    val files = file.listFiles()
    var i = 1
    for (f in files!!) {
        if (f.isDirectory) {
            if(f.list().isNotEmpty()){
                try {
                    val layout = LinearLayout(this)
                    layout.id = i

                    val btnGreen = ImageButton(this)
                    btnGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.play)

                    btnGreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

                    layout.addView(btnGreen)
                    root.addView(layout)

                    btnGreen.setOnClickListener {
                        intent = Intent(this, Play::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("file",f).toString()
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                } 
                catch (e: Exception) {}
            }
        }
    }
    val layout = LinearLayout(this)
    val scroll = HorizontalScrollView(this)
    scroll.addView(root)
    layout.addView(scroll)
    setContentView(layout)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another xml file with the grid layout.

Whenever the user clicks on GridLayout or when you want to change it, just load the new xml, add the children views to the GridLayout xml.

Is this what you wanted?

**EDIT:
ACTUAL CODE ADDED (In Plain Java)**

Kotlin and Java can be used together. If a problem, just change **variable statement, for loop, try catch exception & method calling as in Kotlin + Your other implementation for** `button.onClick`

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
    gridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(4);
    File file = new File("/sdcard/MedProRecordings/").getAbsoluteFile();
    if (file.isDirectory() == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    int i = 1;
    for (File f: files) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            if(f.list().length > 0 ){
                try {
                    /*val layout = LinearLayout(this)
                    layout.id = i*/

                    ImageButton btnGreen = new ImageButton(this);
                    btnGreen.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                    btnGreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    Log.d("GRID LAYOUT TRY", f.getName());

                    gridLayout.addView(btnGreen);
                    /*root.addView(layout)*/

                    btnGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Intent intent = Intent(this, Play::class.java)
                            //intent.putExtra("file",f).toString()
                            //startActivity(intent)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    /*; {
                        intent = Intent(this, Play::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("file",f).toString()
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }*/
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

**Remaining:** Add the grid layout to the scroll layout. In case you are switching between both, just remove the LinearLayout from the scroll Layout and add this

**TESTED ON MY PHONE & IT WORKS**

Comment: No, This code is in the linear layout, I want it in Grid layout. I am trying to Convert it but not working. Thank you for the response though

Comment: Thank you So much for the answer